# How Dynamic binding works in java

Tags: oop

I am beginner to java and trying to understand Dynamic binding

when i come across this below example,

```
class Animal{}  

class Dog extends Animal{  
 public static void main(String args[]){  
  Dog d1=new Dog();  
 }  
}
```

> Here d1 is an instance of Dog class, but it is also an instance of
>   Animal.

here what i dont understand is,How d1 is also become an instance of Animal class when you do inherit in java.

Can someone explain this concept.

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand in this. That's how it is. Dog is an Animal.

Comment: A sub class has an 'is a' relationship with its superclass. This means that a sub class is a special kind of its super class. When we talk in terms of objects, a sub class object can also be treated as a super class object. And hence, we can assign the reference of a sub class object to a super class variable type. However, the reverse is not true. A reference of a super class object may not be assigned to a sub class variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why they say "d1 is also an instance of `Animal`", what they really mean is that `d1` can be used like an instance of `Animal`. You can use `d1` to do everything an instance of `Animal` can do, including but not limited to:

- Passing `d1` to an `Animal` parameter

  ```
  public static void method(Animal a) { ... }
  ...
  method(d1); // compiles!
  ```
- Assigning `d1` to a variable of type `Animal`

  ```
  Animal myAnimal = d1;
  ```
- Calling methods that is in the `Animal` class

  ```
  d1.move();
  ```

The reason why you can do all these is all because of that `extends` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic binding occurs during the run time.It is also known as Late binding as it occurs in the run time.The type of the object cannot be determined during the compile time.The parent class and the child class has the same method but the method is overridden. 
Simple example to understand Dynamic binding

```
class Animal{
    void eat(){
    System.out.println("Animal is Eating");
    }
    }

    class Dog extends Animal{
    void eat(){
    System.out.println("Dog is Eating");
    }
    }

class Test{
public static void main(String [] args){
Animal obj = new Animal();
obj.eat(); // displays Animal is Eating
Animal obj1 = new Dog(); // reference of the parent class
obj1.eat(); // displays Dog is Eating

}
}
```